# Should the c++1y tag refer to c++17?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

Now that C++ 14 is official, shouldn't the c++1y tag be changed to refer to what will likely be C++17?

Comment: Getting only four hits on "c++1z" on Google, and given that g++ "-std=c++1y" implements some C++17 features, not to mention being a part of said community and having never heard this term, I think the down votes are a little harsh. (I do find two items tagged c++1z now, but I swear I checked earlier and did not.)

Comment: Clang has `-std=c++1z`. GCC doesn't implement any C++1z stuff yet. On meta, people usually use downvotes to refer to disagreement. But that's supposed to be for [meta-tag:feature-request]s not so much [tag:discussion]. Nevertheless, the line is blurred.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. The C++ community calls the stuff after C++1y to be C++1z. Naming C++1y to be something else will only add confusion.

On the context of tags, [c++1y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b1y) has already been 'synonymised' to point to [c++14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) so a new tag, [c++1z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b1z) should be used for stuff post-C++14.

Comment: The "z" is for conceptz.

Comment: @KerrekSB Conceptz are postponed to C++20 anyway ;-)